# Shutdown remote naming service in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I need to shutdown port 1099 in Wildfly 10.1. This port normally used for remote JNDI/RMI and in Wildfly 10.1, the remote naming system has a 
[security vulnerability][1].

The straightforward solution will be to configure a firewall to not allow traffic on 1099 port, but this is not acceptable by our client. I thought it possible to configure WF to not use remote JNDI/RMI but can't figure out how to configure it.

The JBoss documentation on Remote JNDI Interface says that you can deactivate the remote JNDI interface by executing the following command via CLI interface:

```
/subsystem=naming/service=remote-naming:remove
```

and it seems really stopping the service, but once you do server 'reload' the Wildfly resumes connection on the port 1099.

Comment: Have you tried removing `<remote-naming>` element from your `standalone-*.xml`?

Comment: Yep, tried, seems not changing anything.